# Where with a has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

A given `Car` has many `features` which are connected through `listed_features`. How can I find all `cars` which have the `features` with the `ids` `1` AND `2` AND `3`? The `cars` can have more `features` but they have to have the first three `features`.

The setup:

```
rails g model Car name:string
rails g model Feature name:string
rails g model ListedFeature car:references feature:references
```

**app/models/car.rb**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listed_features
  has_many :features, through: :listed_features
end
```

**app/models/listed_features.rb**

```
class ListedFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :feature
end
```

**app/models/features.rb**

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here may be to state that you need to get three matches from the features table.

```
id_list = [1, 2, 3]

Car.joins(:features).
    where(features: { id: id_list }).
    references(:features).
    group(:id).
    having("count(*) = ?", id_list.size)
```

Another approach would be to have a scope on Car for has_feature:

```
def self.has_feature(feature_id)
  where(CarFeature.where("car_features.car_id = cars.id and car_features.feature_id = ?", feature_id).exists)
end
```

You can then:

```
Car.has_feature(1).has_feature(2).has_feature(3)
```

... or make it more elegant with another class method that accepts an array of features and then applies the has_feature scope multiple times for you.

It would generate very efficient SQL.

Comment: Does this guarantee that the car has features 1 and 2 and 3? `id: id_list` will basically do 1 or 2 or 3 and the count only makes sure that there are three features. Doesn't a car with features 3,4,5 match this query?

Comment: It is a count of the number of rows in the features table that have those id's and which join to the cars table row. So cars will be returned if they have at least the features required. the presence of any other features is ignored.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the SQL it generates, and any error message?